# How do I align the 2 stacked elements using the same background image so it looks like one image?

Tags: html, css

The header of my website's homepage consists of the following layout:

```
<header>
  <div class="navbar-lock"></div>
  <div class="hero"></div>
</header>
```

Where `div.navbar-lock` is a fixed navigation with an initial height of 90px, and `div.hero` contains some header text. Visually, I want to give the appearance that one background image (2000px x 481px) spans the height and width of both. On scroll, the fixed navbar's background will be the top 90px of the image; when the scroll position is back at the top of the page, the header once again appears as one background image.

What I've tried:

**Approach A**:

```
header {
  background: #F60 url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}
div.navbar-lock {
  background: #F60 url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 90px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Approach B** (crop the image into 2):

```
div.navbar-lock {
  background: #F60 url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}
div.hero {
  background: #F60 url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 -90px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  padding: 80px 0 134px; // padding to properly position its text
}
```

But in both attempts, I was unable to get the image(s) to line up properly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

I would put the header and the hero div's into a parent div. And would put the image onto the parent div.